# How to Improve Linq query perfomance regarding Trim()

Tags: c#, performance, linq, linq-to-sql, query-performance

Our company tables were created with fields with padded spaces.

I don't have access/permissions to make changes to the DB.

However, I noticed that when I create LINQ queries using the Trim() function, the performance decreases quite a bit.

A query as simple as this shows that performance decrease:

```
Companies
.Where(c => c.CompanyName.Equals("Apple"))
.Select(c => new {
  Tick = c.Ticker.Trim(),
  Address = c.Address.Trim()
});
```

Is there a way to change the query so that there is no loss in performance?

Or does this rest solely with my DBA?

Comment: I'd say try to clean up the database, first. It's generally *much* easier for all parties involved to ensure that the data is clean before it goes into the database than to try to deal with messy data afterwards.

Comment: Can you pad the `"Apple"` with the right amount of spaces? Does it work without the `.Trim()` call? Can you use `.TrimEnd()` instead?

Comment: @Gabe you're right.  The Where clause works without the .Trim() call.  But it doesn't seem to improve the performance for the .Select.

Comment: If the query has the same results and performance without the `.Trim()` call, then what is the decreased from?

Answer (score 4):

Quick solution is to pad your company name before giving it to the query. For example, if the column is `char(50)`:

```
var paddedName = "Apple".PadRight(50);
var result = Companies
 .Where(c => c.CompanyName.Equals(paddedName))
 .Select(c => new {
     Tick = c.Ticker.Trim(),
     Address = c.Address.Trim()
 });
```

However, you should consider correcting the database to avoid further issues.

Comment: will this solution work if datatype is NVarchar(50) and not char(50)?

Comment: Yes. As long as you know the data is padded to a certain length, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't try the performance if we use "Like" statement to do first round filter, and make it .ToList(), second round only internally do equal check without call Database.

```
var result = (Companies
            .Where(c => c.CompanyName.StartsWith("Apple"))
            .Select(c => new
            {
                Tick = c.Ticker.Trim(),
                Address = c.Address.Trim()
            })).ToList();

 var result1=result
            .Where(c=>c.CompanyName.Trim().Equals("Apple")) 
            .Select(c => c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than Entity Framework, linq-to-sql can sometimes switch to linq-to-objects under the hood when it encounters method calls that can't be translated to SQL. So if you do

```
....
.Select(c => new {
  Tick = c.Ticker.TrimEnd().TrimStart(),
  Address = c.Address.TrimEnd().TrimStart()
```

you will notice that the generated SQL no longer contains `LTRIM(RTRIM())`, but only the field name and that the trims are executed in client memory. Apparently, somehow the `LTRIM(RTRIM())` causes a less efficient query plan (surprisingly).

Maybe only `TrimEnd()` suffices if there are no leading spaces.

Further, I fully agree with p.s.w.g. that you should go out of your way to try and clean up the database in stead of fixing bad data in queries. If you can't do this job, find the right persons and twist their arms.